# <div> with margin-left and right set to auto becomes uncentered >1634px

Tags: html, css

I have a div, `.instagram_grid` which has `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to auto, is relatively positioned, and has a width which for browse sizes 900px >makes the div be centered nicely in the page.

when I have the simple structure in the context of the rest of the CSS for a single page, the  no longer becomes centered at browser width >1684px. In the Fiddle that follows I only have two lines that modify the div as a whole (and one just sets the background to pink). There are no media queries present, which suggests that it is the effect of some unseen preceding div/element causing the behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/m561tpnL/6/

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is what is expected with that markup.

The element is centered, but then you use relative positioning to show it 500px to the right of where it actually would be.

Comment: it isn't the #white-bckgd, but rather the `.instagram_grid`

Comment: @Thalatta: Sorry, I was looking at the element where I vould see that behaviour. I can't repeat the behaviour in the fiddle for that element, as my screen is only 1920x1080.

Comment: you can just zoom in to simulate bigger resolutions

Comment: @Thalatta: That's a good idea, but I don't know if it actually emulates the resolution. I can't repeat the problem that way either.

Answer (score 0):

The `.calc-text` div above the `.instagram_grid` div causes its parent to overflow by setting `margin-left:auto` while simultaneously setting `left:` to a negative value, which isn't valid CSS.